# Triangle Law of Vector Addition

Tags: vectors, geometry

I know this is a trivial question, but I just wanted to clear my doubt. Using the triangle of vector addition, the resultant of two forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ is given by $$\sqrt{F_1^2 + F_2^2 + 2F_1F_2\cos\phi}$$
In this formula, am I supposed to take only the magnitudes of $F_1$ and $F_2$ or am I supposed to include their signs as well?

Comment: What do you mean by their sign? They are vectors, they don't have a sign unless you define a sign convention. Also if you are talking about magnitude, then magnitude of a vector is always $>0$.

Comment: I mean, suppose, F1= 5N and F2= −10N, so am I supposed to write √((5²)+(−10²)+2.(5).(-10).cosθ) ?

Comment: You are applying the law of cosines to the sides of a triangle. The magnitude of the forces are all positive.The angle is measured between the two vectors.  By the way, the term with the cosine should be negative. Only the components of a vector can be negative, and that's after you define a coordinate system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Vectors have no sign

See, forces do not have a sign, and for that matter, vectors have no sign. They just have a direction and a magnitude. Their direction is defined using [unit vectors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) and these unit vectors can be arbitrarily chosen. Also the $\phi$ in your equation is the angle between two forces. And the $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the magnitudes of the corresponding forces and magnitudes of vectors are always positive.

---

#### Your specific doubt

We only have to take the magnitude of the forces without sign. But you have to be careful in  finding $\cos \phi$. In the example of $F_1= 5 \: \mathrm N$ and $F_2= -10 \: \mathrm N$, the value of $\phi$ is $180^{\circ}$ or $\pi$ and hence $\cos\phi= -1$. This means that although you will substitute $F_1$ and $F_2$ without sign, still the $2F_1F_2\cos\phi$ term will be negative.